# defining SQS endpoint in SNS Terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, definition

I have a SQS Terraform module in which I defined the queue name as below

`main_queue_name = "app-sqs-env-${var.env_name}"`

by defining the `env_name` in a separate file and I am able to create a queue with the desired name.

Now I want to create an SNS topic and want the queue to be subscribed to this topic.

when I create the SNS topic using `sns_topic_name = "app-sns-env-${var.env_name}"` I an able to create the topic as expected

How do I define the sqs_endpoint in the SNS module, I want to use `${var.env_name}` in this endpoint definition as we pass different names for different environments.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to subscribe an SQS queue to an SNS topic we have to do the following:

```
# Create some locals for SQS and SNS names
locals {
  sqs-name = "app-sqs-env-${var.env-name}"
  sns-name = "app-sns-env-${var.env-name}"
}

# Inject caller ID for being able to use the account ID
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}


# Create a topic policy. This will allow for the SQS queue to be able to subscribe to the topic
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns-topic-policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Subscribe",
      "SNS:Receive",
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      variable = "SNS:Endpoint"

      # In order to avoid circular dependencies, we must create the ARN ourselves
      values = [
        "arn:aws:sqs:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${local.sqs-name}",
      ]
    }

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:sns:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${local.sns-name}"
    ]

    sid = "sid-101"
  }
}

# Create a queue policy. This allows for the SNS topic to be able to publish messages to the SQS queue
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sqs-queue-policy" {
  policy_id = "arn:aws:sqs:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${local.sqs-name}/SQSDefaultPolicy"

  statement {
    sid    = "example-sns-topic"
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions = [
      "SQS:SendMessage",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:sqs:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${local.sqs-name}"
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"

      values = [
        "arn:aws:sns:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${local.sns-name}"
      ]
    }
  }
}

# Create the SNS topic and assign the topic policy to it
resource "aws_sns_topic" "sns-topic" {
  name         = local.sns-name
  display_name = local.sns-name
  policy       = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns-topic-policy.json
}

# Create the SQS queue and assign the queue policy to it
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs-queue" {
  name   = local.sqs-name
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs-queue-policy.json
}

# Subscribe the SQS queue to the SNS topic
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "sns-topic" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.sns-topic.arn
  protocol  = "sqs"
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.sqs-queue.arn
}
```

I hope the code and the comments above make sense. There is an example on the Terraform [documentation for aws_sns_topic_subscription](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription) which is way more complex, but also usable.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the circular ARN issue when creating the policy you can use the `aws_sqs_queue_policy` to attach the policy after creation e.g.

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "topic-name"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue" {
  name = "queue-name"
}

# Queue policy allowing send messages from the required topic
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "queue_policy_document" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sqs:SendMessage"]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    resources = [aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn]
    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]
    }
  }
}

# Attach the queue policy
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "queue_policy" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.queue.id
  policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.queue_policy_document.json
}

# subscribe queue to the topic
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "topic_subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn
  protocol  = "sqs"
}
```